# Delete file after sent over email

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm trying to see if you would be able to delete a file after sent over email in Laravel

```
Mail::send('emails.attendance', ['user' => $authUser], function ($m) use ($authUser) {
    $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
    $m->to($authUser->email, $authUser->first_name.' '.$authUser->last_name);
    $m->subject('Faith App - Attendance Data '.$authUser->id);

    $m->attach($filePath)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
});
```

I'm just wondering if `->deleteFileAfterSend(true)` This would work with emails or would I have to delete after the email has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

Basically [deleteFileAfterSend](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.php#L310) will unlink the file only when binary file response in process and then you can try `unlink()`

```
unlink($filePath);
```

If your file is from storage you can use:

```
Storage::delete($filePath);
```

So the final code will look like:

```
Mail::send('emails.attendance', ['user' => $authUser], function ($m) use ($authUser) {
    $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
    $m->to($authUser->email, $authUser->first_name.' '.$authUser->last_name);
    $m->subject('Faith App - Attendance Data '.$authUser->id);

    $m->attach($filePath);
});


if(!Mail::failures()){
    //Unlink the attachement file from local
    unlink($filePath);

    //delete file from storage
    //Storage::delete($filePath);//Uncomment this, if using storage
}
```

Comment: I just have something i need to fix then i will be testing this and I'll let you know how i got on

Comment: I reckon it should

Comment: So it's helping?

Comment: @SCRATK: Any result?